# How to integrate mirrorlink common api in android Application

Tags: android, mirrorlink

friends I am new in **mirrorlink common Api**.I don't know to enable mirror link service in android application.**Please anyone tell me steps and any tutorial link**.

I already do following things :-

1. I get developer account from mirrorlink.com.
2. I attached certificate with my app(that get from software that available from https://causeway.carconnectivity.org) Documents.
3. I saved device EMI number in my ACMS account (https://acms.carconnectivity.org)
4. Now I know I missing mirror link code for launching and terminate all this code and permission in manifest file.

Actually, I don't know how to code in the application for mirrorlink. **please help me for step no.4**

Answer (score 0):

The launch and terminate UPnP code should be placed in the MainActivity. For certification purposes, your app needs to handle the Terminate intent without coming to the foreground (if it is in the background). Even if you don't respond to the intents, the app should be usable in MirrorLink.

You don't need to do anything extra to enable framebuffer streaming, or audio streaming. (Though providing context information via IContextManager.setFramebufferContextInformation and IContextManager.setAudioContextInformation is needed to make sure that the head unit knows what is being provided to it.)